# cluster location in graphviz python

Tags: python, graphviz, dot

Is there a way to make this graphviz output 
[image]

looks like [image]

I am using subgraphs, to merge the 4 clusters with the tree graph

Comment: change `rankdir` at the outermost level?

Comment: It's TB , and i wish of there is a way to change rankdir for each subgraph

Answer (score 0):

Googling found an answer: http://www.graphviz.org/content/subgraph-different-rankdir
Essentially, subgraphs can't have their own rankdir, but you can get the effect you want by placing invisible links between the top-level objects, causing them to be laid out top-to-bottom.

Comment: Invisible edges will affect all nodes, they can't be used for a subgraph only,

Comment: look at the linked article, I think it may lead you to a solution.

Comment: I tried it, it works, but all edges shall be invisible

Comment: can you add your graph to the question?