# graphviz python neural network layer alignment

Tags: python, networkx, graphviz

I'm trying to draw specific weight connections in MLP net. What I want to achieve is

[image: centered]

Straightforward graphviz drawing *tilts* the graph w.r.t. drawn edges

[image: tilted]

```
from graphviz import Graph

graph = Graph(directory='graphs', format='png',
              graph_attr=dict(ranksep='2', rankdir='LR', color='white', splines='line'),
              node_attr=dict(label='', shape='circle', width='0.1'))


def draw_cluster(name, length):
    with graph.subgraph(name=f'cluster_{name}') as c:
        c.attr(label=name)
        for i in range(length):
            c.node(f'{name}_{i}')


draw_cluster('input', 10)
draw_cluster('output', 4)

source_active = [0, 1, 2, 3]
sink_active = [2, 3]

for i_input in source_active:
    for i_output in sink_active:
        graph.edge(f'input_{i_input}', f'output_{i_output}')

graph.view()
```

If I add invisible edges between not connected weights, I do force my graph being centered:
[image: centered with invisible edges]

```
for i_input in set(range(10)).difference(source_active):
    for i_output in set(range(4)).difference(sink_active):
        graph.edge(f'input_{i_input}', f'output_{i_output}', style='invis')
```

But at what cost! My layers can have >1000 neurons with only tens of connections. Maybe [networkx](https://github.com/networkx/networkx) can help, I haven't played with it.

Similar questions that don't help me:

1. [cluster location in graphviz python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43353586/cluster-location-in-graphviz-python)
2. [GraphViz - alignment of subgraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43599738/graphviz-alignment-of-subgraph)

Comment: With networkx you can create the dictionary `pos` so that `pos[node]` is the `(x,y)` coordinates of `node`.  Then draw it with `nx.draw(G, pos)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49127813/graphviz-python-neural-network-layer-alignment#answer-49199028):

```py
from graphviz import Graph

graph = Graph(directory='graphs', format='png',
              graph_attr=dict(ranksep='2', rankdir='LR', color='white', splines='line'),
              node_attr=dict(label='', shape='circle', width='0.1'))

def draw_cluster(name, length):
    with graph.subgraph(name=f'cluster_{name}') as c:
        c.attr(label=name)
        for i in range(length):
            c.node(f'{name}_{i}')

draw_cluster('input', 10)
draw_cluster('output', 4)

source_active = [0, 1, 2, 3]
sink_active = [2, 3]

for i_input in source_active:
    for i_output in sink_active:
        graph.edge(f'input_{i_input}', f'output_{i_output}')

def central_neurons(layer_size: int):
    if layer_size % 2 == 1:
        return {layer_size // 2}
    else:
        return {layer_size // 2, layer_size // 2 - 1}

for source_id in central_neurons(layer_size=10):
    for sink_id in central_neurons(layer_size=4):
        graph.edge(f'input_{source_id}', f'output_{sink_id}',
                   constraint='true', style='invis')

graph.view()
```

and got the result:
[image: MLP network alignment]

I think we can add more settings to make the result more centered. For example we can add [`rank='same'`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/rank/) to align neurons in a cluster and [`constraint='false'`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/constraint/) for edges so that they do not break the alignment of clusters in the center.

```py
from graphviz import Graph

graph = Graph(directory='graphs', format='png',
              graph_attr=dict(ranksep='2', rankdir='LR', color='white', splines='line'),
              node_attr=dict(label='', shape='circle', width='0.1'),
              edge_attr=dict(constraint='false'))

def draw_cluster(name, length):
    with graph.subgraph(name=f'cluster_{name}') as c:
        c.attr(label=name, rank='same')
        for i in range(length):
            c.node(f'{name}_{i}')

draw_cluster('input', 10)
draw_cluster('output', 4)

source_active = [0, 1, 2, 3]
sink_active = [2, 3]

for i_input in source_active:
    for i_output in sink_active:
        graph.edge(f'input_{i_input}', f'output_{i_output}')

def central_neurons(layer_size: int):
    if layer_size % 2 == 1:
        return {layer_size // 2}
    else:
        return {layer_size // 2, layer_size // 2 - 1}

for source_id in central_neurons(layer_size=10):
    for sink_id in central_neurons(layer_size=4):
        graph.edge(f'input_{source_id}', f'output_{sink_id}',
                   constraint='true', style='invis')
graph.view()
```

Result:
[image: MLP network alignment]

Comment: Yes, that's precisely what I did 4 years ago: https://github.com/dizcza/MCMC_BinaryNet/blob/master/monitor/graph.py. I used `constraint='false'` by default and I omitted rank settings. I'm marking your solution as the answer, as there are plenty of variations.

Answer (score 0):

I found the workaround. The trick is you don't have to make all-all connections to center the graph. It's sufficient to connect just central ones for each layer:

```
def central_neurons(layer_size: int):
    if layer_size % 2 == 1:
        return {layer_size // 2}
    else:
        return {layer_size // 2, layer_size // 2 - 1}

for source_id in central_neurons(layer_size=source_size):
    for sink_id in central_neurons(layer_size=sink_size):
        graph.edge(f'input_{source_id}', f'output_{sink_id}', constraint='true', style='invis')
```